# Java Object Oriented Programming Setters and Getters

Tags: java, class, object, interface

Since I have studied programming on my own I thought I should start creating proper classes and variables but I dont seem to quite get it.

I have read that first I need and Interface so I made mine look like this:

```
public interface PitchInterface {
    void setOccuranceTime(float occuranceTime);
    float getOccuranceTime();
    void setPitch(float pitch);
    float getPitch();
}
```

Secondly I made a class that `implements` the `Interface`:

```
public class Pitch implements PitchInterface{

    float occuranceTime;
    float pitch;

    @Override
    public void setOccuranceTime(float occuranceTime) {
        this.occuranceTime = occuranceTime;
    }

    @Override
    public float getOccuranceTime() {
        return occuranceTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPitch(float pitch) {
        this.pitch = pitch;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPitch() {
        return pitch;
    }
}
```

Now I need to give values to Pitch it and this is where I am stuck at the moment.

```
public class Foo {

    Pitch pitch = new Pitch();
    String[] pitches;
    List<Pitch> listOfPitches = new ArrayList<Pitch>();
    List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<Pitch> getListOfPitches(){
    getPitches();
    for (String pitchString: pitches) {
        makeListOfPitches(pitch, pitchString);
    }
    return listOfPitches;
}

public void makeListOfPitches(Pitch pitch, String pitchString){
    pitch.setPitch(getPitchesInfo(pitchString, 0));
    pitch.setOccuranceTime(getPitchesInfo(pitchString, 1));
    listOfPitches.add(pitch);
}

    public List<String> getWordsList(){
        //To-do make words out of Pitches and add them to list
        return wordsList;
    }



    public String[] getPitches() {
        pitches = pitchesRaw.split("\\r?\\n");
        return pitches;
    }

    private float getPitchesInfo(String pitch, int position){
        String[] frequencyAndTime = pitch.split("\\:");
        if(position == 0){
            return Float.parseFloat(frequencyAndTime[0].replace(',', '.'));
        }
        if(position == 1){
            return Float.parseFloat(frequencyAndTime[1].replace(',', '.'));
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    String pitchesRaw = "0,14:23281,61\n" +
            "0,23:53,65\n" +
            "0,37:72,53\n" +
            "0,56:86,09\n" +
            "0,60:88,58\n" +
            "0,65:87,45\n" +
            "0,70:87,11\n" +
            "0,74:89,56\n" +
            "0,79:96,22\n" +
            "0,84:23288,24\n" +
            "0,88:103,92\n" +
            "0,93:107,46\n" +
            "0,98:108,02\n" +
            "1,02:107,51\n" +
            "1,07:104,92\n" +
            "1,11:105,94\n" +
            "1,16:106,40\n";
    }
```

And finally to initialize it from some main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo listOfWordsAndPithes = new Foo();
    List<Pitch> list = listOfWordsAndPithes.getListOfPitches();
    for (Pitch pitch: list) {
        System.out.println(pitch.getPitch());
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am asking for too much but I would like to understand how the `classes` work properly in Java and if I understood the classes and interfaces the correct way. Also how to make new `Pitches`, `get them` and `iterate` over them

**EDIT:** Edited the `Foo` class as was suggested in comments and it gives no errors now. There are still two things I dont seem to understand.
`First` if I print out all the pitches that I should have it only gives me the pitch of the last String added but they all should be different.
`Secondly` if I need to make a `words list` out of pitches by adding multiple `Pitches` into one list (for example add 6 different Pitches into 1 list) and then add those `Pitches` into another list that would be the first element of a new list. Then do I need to make another `class` called `Word` and define there what word is and how to set/get it?
`Thirdly`I read from the comments that using Interface here is not needed. When do I know if it is OK to use an Interface and when not?

Comment: Stackoverflow changed it into that automatically for some reason

Comment: @Michael Also: how? It's not a valid Java class name.

Comment: that class name is terrible use convention, class should start with capital letter. also listOfWordsAndPithes.getWordsList();
    listOfWordsAndPithes.getListOfPitches(); this two are useless if not assigned.

Comment: @MasterYi No. A java class cannot being with a digit.

Comment: @MasterYi I will assign them. It is just to set an example of how I am going to use them.

Comment: To get back on the subject ... what is the problem you are stuck exactly ? This is a bit broad. There is a lot of information, but only see one comment mentionning "_/f i try to use the pitch here to set the variables it says that it cannot resolve the method_" Is that it ? Please  [edit] to expose the problems better, in a [mcve] if possible. And of the answer ... `String pitch` you use the incorrect type in the method. And you use a lot of `String` instead of `Pitch` in general.

Comment: you don't have to use an `interface`. But it is useful in real world cases. not in a small example like this though.

Comment: @JackFlamp well it is a real world case but alright, I guess I will delete the interface. Do i keep the rest of the classes they way to are and try to make them work?

Comment: @AxelH I will try to edit it the way you said

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: an `interface` only for getters / setters is a misuse...